# Create a web client which serves an asmx service (SOAP API)

Tags: c#, .net-core, soap, webclient, soap-client

I need to serve data exposed in a third party asmx service from other webpage to use it on my own API. I used NET 7.0 to create API. To access the URL of this asmx service, it needs a previous login in the website (User, Password) and after that, 4 parameters (Proportioned-> obj, lang, user and password) to access the method. The expected response it must be a JSON response, to attach it and map it. SOAP Client is actually implemented but It gives an error response due login wasn`t added because I don't know how exactly implement it. The code scheme is:

Client Class

```c
public class Repository : IRepository
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public readonly string serviceUrl = Constants;
        public readonly EndpointAddress endpointAddress;
        public readonly BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding;
                
        public Repository(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl);
            basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(endpointAddress.Uri.Scheme.ToLower() == "http" ? BasicHttpSecurityMode.None : BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
            basicHttpBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            basicHttpBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            basicHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            basicHttpBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        }

        public async Task<json_ws_biisSoapClient> GetInstanceAsync()
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => new json_ws_biisSoapClient(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress));
        }

        public async Task<Response<string>> BIISAsync(string obj, string lang, string user, string password)
        {
            Response<string> response = new Response<string>();           
            try
            {
                //Login method should go here (?)

                //ASMX service method that serves API SOAP
                var client = await GetInstanceAsync();
                await client.BIISAsync(obj, lang, user, password);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>("");

                response.Data = dt.ToString();
                response.code = 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.code = 500;
                response.message = ex.Message;
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Interface of Client

```c
public interface IRepository
    {
        Task<json_ws_biisSoapClient> GetInstanceAsync();
        Task<Response<string>> BIISAsync(string obj, string lang, string user, string password);
    }
```

I was thinking about create 2 separates clients, but that's redundant, and I would need help with this implementation.
Any advice will be appreciated.

SOAP Client after execution, gives an html response without much clarity, but makes sense isn't working, due it hasn't any login implementation. Same for Postman.